# Prove that for every $x<y\in \mathbb{R}$ there is a rational number in the interval $(x,y)$

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers, rational-numbers

So I came across this problem and here is my proof, is it valid? I really liked it so I wanted to share it.

We will only use two properties, $\mathbb{N}$ is not bounded from above and $\mathbb{N}$ is well ordered.

Just like many proofs of this problem, we begin with a positive interval.

**Proposition:**

If $x,y\in \mathbb{R}^+$ such that $x<y$, then there is a rational number in the interval $(x,y)$.

Proof:
Suppose $x,y\in\mathbb{R}^+$ such that $x<y$, since $\mathbb{N}$ is not bounded from above there is an $a\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $\frac{1}{n}<x$. Now notice that $0<y-x$, then we have such an $m\in\mathbb{N}$ that $\frac{\frac{1}{n}}{m}<y-x$ which is $\frac{1}{mn}<y-x$. Here notice that since $m\in\mathbb{N}$, $\frac{1}{mn}\le\frac{1}{n}<x$ implying $\frac{1}{mn}<x$ and the inequality $ \frac{1}{mn}<y-x$ can be read as:
$$x+\frac{1}{mn}<y$$
Now notice that there is a $c\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $\frac{1+c}{mn}>x$, since $\mathbb{N}$ is well ordered we can pick the smallest of such $c$'s, when we pick it that way we must have $\frac{1+(c-1)}{mn}\le x$, summarizing in:
$$\frac{c}{mn}\le x<\frac{c+1}{mn}$$
Now notice that if $\frac{c}{mn}\le x$ then $\frac{c}{mn}+\frac{1}{mn}\le x+\frac{1}{mn}$ and since $x+\frac{1}{mn}<y$ we have $\frac{c}{mn}+\frac{1}{mn}<y$ which is essentialy:
$$\frac{c+1}{mn}<y$$
Here we have found our rational number because we have picked our $c\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\frac{1+c}{mn}>x$ implying:
$$x<\frac{c+1}{mn}<y$$
Since $c+1\in\mathbb{N}$ and $mn\in\mathbb{N}$, $\frac{c+1}{mn}\in\mathbb{Q}$ and $\frac{c+1}{mn}\in(x,y)$.

Now we can easily show that there is a rational number in any interval $(x,y)$

**Theorem:**
If $x,y\in \mathbb{R}$ such that $x<y$, then there is a rational number in the interval $(x,y)$.

Proof:
Suppose $x,y\in \mathbb{R}$ such that $x<y$, then since $\mathbb{N}$ is not bounded from above we have such an $a\in \mathbb{N} $ that $x+a>0$ and since $y>x$, $y+a>x+a>0$ also. Then by the proposition we have a rational number $q$ in the interval $(x+a,y+a)$. Here since $a\in\mathbb{N}\subset\mathbb{Q}$ and $q\in\mathbb{Q}$, $q-a\in\mathbb{Q}$ and $q-a\in(x,y)$ as desired.

Thank you for reading!

Comment: Proof looks good, although a little wordy (you can replace all $mn$ with just $k$ and it still works, and the proof for $x,y\in \mathbb{R}^+$ actually applies to $x,y\in \mathbb{R}$). You have also implicitly made use of the Archimedean property of real numbers in your proof, which you should be aware of in case you are not

Comment: Ata, you could prove it more succinctly, look at my answer. If $z$ is any real number, $\lfloor z\rfloor$ is the floor function, i.e. the greatest integer less than or equal to $z$. The floor function is well-defined since $\mathbb N$ is not bounded from above and is well-ordered.

Comment: How have you defined $\mathbb{R}$? Any proof of such basic facts will depend a lot on what you are starting with.

Comment: All you need for this is Archimedes, and then the proof should be a couple of lines…

Comment: @AdamRubinson, could you write a proof which only uses the Archimedean property ? Are you sure your proof does not need any well-ordering property?

Comment: @Angelo What is wrong with using the well-ordering property for subsets of real numbers?

Comment: @AdamRubinson, obviously I refer to subsets of $\mathbb N$ or subsets of $\mathbb Z$ bounded from below.

Comment: @AdamRubinson, in general the subsets of real numbers does not have any well-ordering property, so it is not possible to use it.

Comment: Ok yeah - I'm not used to the "well-ordering principle". Obviously, a proof must rely on the well-ordering principle/property of the natural numbers. When I said you "only need Archimedes", I guess I could have also said "and the well-ordering principle" [although this seems arbitrary to me, as you also need all of the other axioms required for the proof like Peano's axioms etc, if you want to be pedantic.]

Answer (score 1):

**Theorem :**
If $x,y\in \mathbb{R}$ such that $x<y$, then there is a rational number in the interval $(x,y)$.

**Proof :**

Let $\;n=\left\lfloor\dfrac1{y-x}\right\rfloor+1\in\mathbb N\;\;,\;\;m=\lfloor nx\rfloor+1\in\mathbb Z\;.$

It results that $\;n>\dfrac1{y-x}\;,\;m>nx\;,\;$ moreover ,

$x\!=\!\dfrac{nx}n\!<\!\dfrac mn\!=\!\dfrac{\lfloor nx\rfloor\!+\!1}n\!\leqslant\!\dfrac{nx\!+\!1}n\!=\!x\!+\!\dfrac1n\!<\!x\!+\!(y\!-\!x)\!=\!y\;.$

Hence , there exists $\;\dfrac mn\in\mathbb Q\;$ such that $\;x<\dfrac mn<y\;.$

Answer (score 1):

Since $y-x>0,\ $ by Archimedes $\ \exists\ n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $n > \frac{1}{y-x}.\ $ Let $n$ be one such positive integer. Note also that $\ ny > nx+1.\ $

Let $k_1$ be the greatest integer $\leq nx.\ $ If $\ k_1+1 \leq nx,\ $ then this contradicts the definition of $k_1.$ Therefore $k_1 + 1> nx.$ Therefore we have:

$\ k_1\leq nx < nx + 1 < ny,\ \implies nx<k_1+1 \leq nx + 1 < ny,\implies x\overset{(\times\frac{1}{n})}{<} \frac{k_1+1}{n}<y,\ $ i.e. $\ \frac{k_1+1}{n} \in (x,y).$

Comment: You are using well-ordering property of subsets of $\mathbb Z$ bounded from below, otherwise you cannot say there exists the greatest integer $\leqslant nx$. Moreover, you should write $$nx<k_1+1\leqslant nx + 1 < ny$$ instead of $$nx<k_1+1 < nx + 1 < ny$$.

Comment: Yes but so what? Did the OP say we're not allowed to?

Comment: But in a previous comment you wrote “All you need for this is Archimedes”. Actually we also need well-ordering property.

Comment: True although arbitrary: we also need Peano's axioms but neither of us have mentioned that.... I mean... your proof uses W-O principle also, no?

Comment: Of course we need other properties and axioms. For this reason, “all you need” is not acceptable.

Comment: Of course, my proof uses well-ordering principle, otherwise I could not write the floor function. Your way of saying “all you need” when the OP had already said that he was using well-ordering principle, made me think that your proof did not need it. For this reason I asked you to write your proof.

Comment: Well, I go by Rudin PMA, and he uses W-O principle (and implicitly, the Peano axioms and probably a few other axioms) to prove the Archimedean property of $\mathbb{R}$ (I think). So, by stating I'm going to use the Archimedean property, I'm implicitly saying that I'm using the W-O principle. I'm not certain of this, but does this make sense? Also the wording, "all you need is $X$" makes sense to me if (a) you can prove with $X$, and (b) you cannot prove with anything simpler than $X$. So in this sense, "All you need is Archimedes" makes sense to me, but I can see how it is ambiguous.

Comment: If you had written it in your first comment instead of writing “all you need is Archimedes”, I would not have misunderstood you. I think we do not need to keep on talking about it because now I know what you meant. Have a nice day !